# Solidity: extracting (slicing) characters from a string

Tags: solidity, string

Perhaps a double, but I couldn't find an answer here, and neither in strings library.

I have a `string public string = "ABCDEFG"`

I need to put together a function that iterates through the characters of the string and returns the characters that are in between the input numbers.

for example, `function getSlice(uint256 begin, uint256 end)` would return `CDE` if passed 2 and 6.

What would be the best way to create such a function?

Comment: Why are you doing this in Solidity? It seems like something that would be much better done off-chain.

Comment: I know, but this is a result of an Oraclize callback function, and I need to slice it to use in another function.

Comment: @smarx That may not be the best solution, but I need that. Could you please help?

Comment: There's a library for string manipulation https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract test{

    function getSlice(uint256 begin, uint256 end, string text) public pure returns (string) {
        bytes memory a = new bytes(end-begin+1);
        for(uint i=0;i<=end-begin;i++){
            a[i] = bytes(text)[i+begin-1];
        }
        return string(a);    
    }


}
```

The variable `text` is the text that you want to slice.

Hope it helps

Comment: Could you please help me with a modification of this function? I will always have 14, 15 or 16 character strings. The issue is - I don't know when I will receive which type of the string. However, I do know, that I want to drop all the characters of the string before the 12, so that I end up with the last 2, 3 or 4 characters.

Comment: please post this as a new question and let me know.

Comment: this just reverts for me...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter, gas-efficient answer without **for** loops:

```
function trim(string calldata str, uint start, uint end) external pure returns(string memory) {
    return str[start:end];
}
```

This takes a string and `start` and `end` positions

Answer (score 0):

i just developed a solidity library that solves this problem and possibly almost any other you might have with strings, it's called 'string-utils-lib', you can check it on my github [String Utils Lib](https://github.com/OsoTega/string-utils-lib). With the library, you can create a substring from the string this way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18

    import {StringUtilsLib} from "string-utils-lib/StringUtilsLib.sol"
    
    contract UseContract{
        using StringUtilsLib for string;

        function spliceStringExample() public pure returns(string memory){
          string memory a = "abcdefg";
          return a.substring(2, 5);
    
          //Expected cdef
      }
    }
```

The substring() function would return a new string with the specified points