# How can I add an element to the array at an index of my choosing while altering the array size accordingly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, solidity-0.8.x

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
uint256[] array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

I am familiar with how to add an element to an array using `array.push(100);` which would make the array look like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,100];
```

How can I add an element to the array at an index of my choosing while altering the array size accordingly?

For instance, how do I add an element to the array at: `index [3]` or more specific `array[3] = 999` while also increasing the size of the array accordingly?

The desired result would look something like this:

```
[1,2,3,999,4,5,6,7,8,100];
```

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78559/how-can-i-slice-bytes-strings-and-arrays-in-solidity

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78559/how-can-i-slice-bytes-strings-and-arrays-in-solidity)

I do see that this answer only applies to calldata, however.
Here is my "top of brain" naive / brute force approach.

```
pseudo code:

function sliceNDice(string[] originalArr, uint replaceAtIndex, string insertMe) internal pure {
  tmpArr = [];
  for (let i=0; i < originalArr.length; i++) {
    if (i == replaceAtIndex) {
      tmpArr.push(insertMe);
      tmpArr.push(originalArr[i]);
    } else {
      tmpArr.push(originalArr[i]);
    }
  }
  return tmpArr;
}

// use like
sliceNDice(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 1, 'foobarbaz'); // ['foo', 'foobarbaz', 'bar', 'baz']
```

This is a super brute method and the code above certainly has syntax errors and can be improved (one push for example).  I just wanted to give you an alternative way to think about this problem. Good luck!