# Split a string into two at places where ? occurs

Tags: solidity

I am newbie to solidity. I am trying to split a string at into different based on '?' appearing. For example

```
test/?stat=true  -----> test/  and stat=true
test/?stat=true?newstat=false  -----> test/    stat=true and  newstat=false
```

how this can be done. I tried using string utils library but it gives me a bunch of errors

https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils

I tried splitting like this as an example (sample code)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
import "github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/src/strings.sol";

contract Contract {
    using strings for *;

    var s = "foo bar baz".toSlice();
    var foo = s.split(" ".toSlice());
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
from solidity:
ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
 --> trial.sol:7:5:
  |
7 |     var s = "foo bar baz".toSlice();
  |     ^^^
```

Comment: What errors is the stringutils library giving you?

Answer (score 1):

The `var` keyword was deprecated in Solidity 0.4.20 (see [release notes](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.20)).

This previous answer should help with what you want to do: [How can I slice bytes, strings, and arrays in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78559/how-can-i-slice-bytes-strings-and-arrays-in-solidity)