# Convert a string in scientific notation to a number

Tags: solidity, string, solidity-0.6.x, uint256, conventions

my smart contract uses an Oracle to retrieve the price. The price is returned as a string in scientific notation, for example, "**3e-8**". How I can convert this to number (uint)? The token has 18 decimals, so the final value in this example should be 30000000000.

Comment: Be aware that this (and string manipulation in general) is going to be costly.

Comment: I know but do I have no choice, as the API returns data in such format

Comment: Well, first question that arises - does it ALWAYS come in that format (i.e., <decimal digits>e<+-><decimal digits>)? Or does it possibly come in regular decimal notation?

Comment: This is the rate of myToken/ETH, so unless myToken is worth not a lot, it will come in that notation. I am using coingecko API.

Comment: You didn't answer the question!

Comment: I don't know, I started working on this project yesterday. For now, it always comes like that, but who knows if in the future Coingecko decides to change their API.

Comment: So you have a bit of a dependency problem here. I've never heard of this Coingecko  service that you're mentioning, but I'd assume that they have some sort of way to configure this output, which in its current form is a problem not only to you, but to anyone else using this service. If they're not aware of that, then they will be when they find out that all of their clients are compelled to resolve this problem in their contracts. It is worse enough to parse a regular decimal string, let alone one that comes in scientific notation (let alone one that may come in both notations alternating).

Comment: Provable has a parseInt function but it converts 3e-8 to 38 (probably just skips all the non integers in string), so it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Share this function here and someone will be able to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: There are no other APIs that I am aware of that returns the price of this token. Also, coingecko API is public, so it is easily implemented.

Comment: I am importing provable and it is providing me parseInt out the box, the code for it can be found here: https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/provableAPI_0.6.sol

Comment: There are more than 1300 lines of code in there! Please do a little bit of an effort, find that function and post it **as part of your question**.

Comment: What do you mean API? Do you receive that string in an off-chain script, and then send it **as is** to your contract???

Comment: yes, you can play with this API: https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3 Provable allows calling and getting values from off-chain.

Comment: You mean `3e8 == 300000000`. `3e-8 == 0.00000003`, which is simply zero if you tried to represent that as a `uint256`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Provable's Computation Datasource, to do that https://docs.provable.xyz/#data-sources-computation.

Your use case resembles this example here https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-examples/tree/master/solidity/computation-datasource/url-requests

Just make the relevant request to Coingecko inside a python script and then make the conversion you would expect onchain.

Please note that ARG0, ARG1, ARG2 you find inside the `url-requests.py` script

```
arg = [os.environ['ARG0'], os.environ['ARG1']]

# parse 3rd arg into kwargs if available
if 'ARG2' in os.environ: kwargs = ast.literal_eval(os.environ['ARG2'])
else: kwargs = {}
```

are environment variables defined at Docker level, relative to the values defined into the array given to the `oraclize_query` function defined inside `UrlRequests.sol` code.

The first element of the array specified should contain the IPFS multihash of the uploaded archive. (The value returned by `IPFS add archive.zip`) Then ARG0, ARG1, ... follows

Answer (score 0):

You're either going to have to find a library that does this, or write some string parsing yourself, to extract the signed number after the "e", add that to the ERC20's decimals() return value, and multiply the number before the "e" by 10**result. Other answers have suggested available Solidity code for parsing, but if you roll your own you'll need to do string slicing and character access. Search around.

[Solidity: extracting (slicing) characters from a string](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52246/solidity-extracting-slicing-characters-from-a-string)